# Custom TextView Padding, TextSize Attributes Not Working

Tags: android, textview

So I am trying to create a custom textView which extends the native TextView. However, when I inflate it in a fragment, though attributes like background are working, attributes such as padding and textSize are not working. Even when I add them in the constructor programmatically, they are not working. I must be missing something trivial. Please help.

**CustomView**

```
public class TextBox extends TextView{

    private OneTimeTask oneTimeTask;
    private Integer oneTimeTaskId;

    public TextBox (Context context) {
        super(context);
        appearance();

    }

    public TextBox (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        appearance();
    }

public TextBox (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    appearance();
}

    public void  appearance(){
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            this.setLayoutParams(params);
            this.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.material_micro_text_size));
            this.setPadding((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.material_padding),(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.material_small_padding),(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.material_padding),(int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.material_small_padding));
            this.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
            this.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            this.setText("Not Started");
   }
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
}
```

**Xml**

```
<com.me.p.k.TextBox 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Test"
        android:id="@+id/state"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/pink"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp" />
```

**Edit**

Added part of Karakuri's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the three argument constructor.

```
public TextBox (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    appearance();
}
```

Also, I would not set the attributes in both code and XML, because it's just confusing. Pick one or the other--so far everything I see can be set by defining a style resource and applying that to the view.